# How to pass values to msi through Inno Setup

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup, bootstrapper

I'm using Innosetup as a bootstrapper for my msi setup. It packs the main mis file and other prerequisites. It works fine when we use full UI. Now i want to install the whole setup in silent  mode. For InnoSetup we can give /SILENT OR /VERYSILENT. How can i pass values to msi (i.e., Unlock Key, Features to be installed etc.). If i install msi alone, i can able to give it in a command  line. But when using as a single exe, how can i give it ? should i write any inf or bat  files for this ? The same exe will be used to install in silent mode as well as in full UI.

Waiting for the reply.

Thanks and Regards,
Varun

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
function ParamStr(Index: Integer): String;
```

*Description*:
Returns the Index-th command line parameter passed to Setup or Uninstall.

In your script you can run msi with value from ParamStr[i].

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for mariadb installer. In the run section put:

```
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i {app}\mariadb-5.2.9-win32.msi PORT=3306 PASSWORD=xxxxxx SERVICENAME=MySQL ADDLOCAL=ALL REMOVE=DEVEL,HeidiSQL INSTALLDIR=""C:\mariadb"" /L*v log.txt /qb"; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist
```

My problem was with double quotation marks after /i and once the ones were removed, the installation was performed perfectly and silently (/ qb) and create a log.txt file for mariadb installation.